# Is there a way to crossfade between to RelativeLayouts programmatically and without using xml animations or the Android.R.anim ones?

Tags: android, animation, android-relativelayout

I am creating a relativelayout programmatically in onCreate like this:

```
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(); 

//I add all the views here.

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
rp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
setContentView(rl, rp);
```

And i am currently switching from one to another with:

```
RelativeLayout rn = (RelativeLayout) Framework.layouts(rlo);
if (rn!=null) {setContentView(rn);}
```

Works fine and everything, now, i am trying to add a crossfade effect between the two layouts.

Is there a way to do it programmatically without xml files and without the android.R.anim animations?

For every single question i have made i end up getting answers like better solutions or something, but I have good reasons for this, thanks.